# Chances of a false positive and a false negative respectively?

Tags: probability

A store-bought pregnancy test produces a correct result 99% of the time when a woman is actually pregnant but is only 97% accurate when a woman is not pregnant.  What are the chances of a false positive and a false negative respectively?

So I have tried to solve it and is the false positive 3%?
SO, false positive is when the result shows positive despite her not being pregnant. And for her not being pregnant , the test is 97% accurate. Then, the false positive should be 100-97%?

Comment: "So I have tried to solve it..."  Please click "Edit" above, so that we can see the details of your calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Correct.  A false positive means that the test indicates pregnancy when she is not actually pregnant.  And since the test is $97\%$ accurate when the woman is not pregnant, this implies that the test is wrong $3\%$ of the time in such cases--i.e., produces a positive result when she is not pregnant.

A similar idea applies to the false negative:  since the test is $99\%$ accurate when a woman is pregnant, this means it returns a positive result $99\%$ of the time when a woman is pregnant, and it fails to detect pregnancy $1\%$ of the time (returns negative result) when the woman is pregnant.

I should also point out that this calculation assumes that there are no inconclusive results:  i.e., the test produces either a positive or negative result and no other type of result.